# Design issue on badge process popover in the Chrome browser

Tags: bug

Consider:

[image: the badge progress popover has odd transparent lines going vertically through the badge and text at the top and horizontally under the last two progress bars and text at the bottom.]

I hope the vertical lines are not needed here. And the 4th horizontal line is not aligned properly. Could you please fix this if you thinking it's a bug like me?

**Note:** *The problem occurred in the Chrome browser only. I checked with Firefox (only) and it's working fine.*

> **Chrome browser Version**: Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)